# Show that a piecewise function is continuous but its inverse it not

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

> I have a function, $f:[0,1)\cup[2,3]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> x & x\in[0,1)\\
> x-1 & x\in [2,3]
> \end{cases}$$
>   That I want to show is continuous, but also show its inverse it not.
>
> Here is my proof for continuity:

### Continuity

Let $x_0\in [0,1)$, and suppose that $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$.

Then if $\delta = \epsilon$, $0 < |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |x - x_0| < \delta = \epsilon$.

So $f$ is continuous on the interval $[0,1)$.

Let $x_0\in [2,3]$, and suppose that $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$.

Then if $\delta = \epsilon$, $0 < |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |x - 1 - x_0 + 1| = |x - x_0| < \delta = \epsilon$.

So $f$ is continuous on the interval $[2,3]$.

The above also implies that the limit of $f$ at $x\to 1$ from the left is $1$, and the limit of $f$ as $x\to 2$ from the right is $1$.

Therefore $f$ is continuous.

> My concern with this proof is that it feels like I can do the same thing with the inverse function to show that the inverse function is continuous, even though I know that a choice of $\epsilon = 1/2$ disrupts the continuity. What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm guessing $f(x) = x$ on $[0,2]$ or similar

Comment: @fGDu94 If you mean I might have copied the question down incorrectly, then no, that is not the case. If we look at $x=2$ and choose $\epsilon = 10^-16$, then $\delta$ will be very nearly $1$, which is fine, since we only require that $\epsilon$ becomes arbitrarily close to $0$ as we shrink $\delta$. I am just struggling to construct the proof in a way which does not work for the inverse function.

Comment: What I mean to say is, as it stands, $f$ is not continuous on $[1,2)$

Comment: Fair enough, I'll make the edit that the domain is $[0,1)\cup[2,3]$.

Comment: What is the inverse of $f$ then, you can work it out and get some intuition that way

Answer (score 1):

I feel like $\epsilon-\delta$ shrouds vision while solving this question. Elementary topology is a useful tool here.

---

Note that $[0,1[$ is closed in $[0,1[ \cup [2,3]$ since we for example have $[0,1[ = [0,1] \cap ([0,1[ \cup [2,3])$. Similarly, $[2,3]$ is closed in $[0,1[ \cup [2,3]$. Next, note that your function is continuous restricted to these two subsets. Thus, as a corollary of the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), we see that the function you wrote down is continuous.

---

An inverse, if it exists, can't be continuous. Indeed, suppose to the contrary that such a continuous inverse exists. Then you have a continuous map

$$f^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1[ \cup [2,3]$$

and in particular by continuity it follows that $[0,1[ \cup [2,3]$ is connected, which is not the case. This is the desired contradiction.

---

Here is an answer avoiding topology:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and put $\delta:= \min \{\epsilon, 1/2\}$. Then  if $|x-y| < \delta$, we see that either $x,y \in [0,1[$ or $x,y \in [2,3]$ and it trivially follows that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$, showing that $f$ is uniformly continuous, hence continuous.

Assume to the contrary a continuous inverse exists. Note that $f^{-1}(0) = 0$ and $f^{-1}(2) = 3$ so by the intermediate value theorem, there is a point $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(c) = 1$. This is impossible as the image of $f^{-1}$ is $[0,1[ \cup [2,3]$.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with topology and the course which relates to this is strictly Real Analysis of Several Variables. I have to use either $\epsilon-\delta$ or $\epsilon-N$ as tools here.

Comment: @MurderOfCrows No problem. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MurderOfCrows Is it better now?

Comment: If you insist on an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument to show that the inverse isn't continuous, you must explicitely calculate the inverse, which is not hard but I tried to avoid this. Then, you'll see where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you. The discontinuity in the inverse is not problematic for me, it's my proof for continuity of $f$ that is problematic, because I can see how my proof might justify its inverse being continuous as well.

Comment: Well, your proof looks correct. If you spell out explicitely how you think this same proof also shows the inverse is continuous, I'll tell you where the flaw lies.

Comment: My proof for the continuity of $f$ doesn't contain in it any information about how $\epsilon = 1/2$ is  a valid choice of $\epsilon$, whereas for the inverse function, this choice is invalid and leads to a discontinuity proof.

Comment: Spell out your explicit proof that shows that $f^{-1}$ is continuous and I'll tell you where your flaw is. I can't tell where you go wrong if you don't share your proof attempt!